# How to place app inside of Main content ? Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass, angular-material

I've been struggling to put app inside Main content area. My apps do not show inside of Main content area.
This is my Github https://github.com/FlameDickyHead/Electric-Device-Borrowing-Website/tree/master

** I set up my login page as a default. Basically you have to login first to get into dashboard.

[Main Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Ki4.png)

This is my dashboard.component.html

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="sidenav.mode =='over'" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon *ngIf="!sidenav.opened">menu</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon *ngIf="sidenav.opened">close</mat-icon>
    </button>
    Electric Devices Borrowing Website
    <button mat-button (click)="logout()">
        <mat-icon>logout</mat-icon>
        Logout
    </button>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav="matSidenav">
        <img width="100" height="100" class="avatar mat-elevation-z8" src="assets/image/logoproject.png">
        <h4 class="name">EDBW Company</h4>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <button mat-button class="menu-button" (click)="home()">
            <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
            <span>Home</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="menu-button" (click)="employee()">
            <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
            <span>Employees</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="menu-button">
            <mat-icon>add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>
            <span>Borrowing Devices</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="menu-button">
            <mat-icon>backspace</mat-icon>
            <span>Returning Devices</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="menu-button">
            <mat-icon>list_alt</mat-icon>
            <span>Status Tables</span>
        </button>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <button mat-button class="menu-button">
            <mat-icon>info</mat-icon>
            <span>About us</span>
        </button>
        <button mat-button class="menu-button">
            <mat-icon>help</mat-icon>
            <span>Help</span>
        </button>

    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <div class="content mat-elevation-z4">
            Main Content
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

This is my dashboard.component.ts *Updated*

```
 home() {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home']);
  }
  employee(){
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/employee']);
  }
}
```

This is my app-routing.module.ts  *Updated*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'},
  {path: 'login', component : LoginComponent},
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'employee',
        component: EmployeeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'borrow-device',
        component: BorrowComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'return-device',
        component: ReturnComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'status-table',
        component: StatusComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'about-us',
        component: AboutUsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'help',
        component: HelpComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {path: 'register', component : RegisterComponent},
  {path: 'forgot-password', component : ForgotPasswordComponent},
  {path: 'verify-email', component : VerifyEmailComponent},
];
```

This is my app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: have you tried adding a routerlink to your buttons? routerLink="/yourPathHere"

Comment: I tried it at my buttons  routerLink = "/dashboard" but it seems not showing anything on my main content area. :(

Comment: try it with an <a> tag and see if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 nested `router-outlets`. One is inside `app.component.html`, the other one is inside `dashboard.component.html`. Unfortunately this nested structure is not represented in you route config.

In order to render data at this nested `router-outlet`, you have do define child routes of you dashboard route:

```
{
  path: 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'I-Am-Nested',
      component: WhatEverComponentYouWantToRender,
    },
  ],
},
```

Since I don't know which components should be rendered inside your main-content, you can use it as a template, but have to adjust the component and path yourself.

Comment: There are menus(home,employee,borrowing devices,returning devices,etc) in the dashboard. I want them show up inside of main content when I click the button. Instead of going to different pages. Thanks for your idea. I'll try your idea tomorrow.

Comment: This should work. Just move these routes to children array of dashboard component. You will then be able to render them e.g. via URL `/dashboard/home`

Comment: I tried your idea this afternoon. when I clicked the button. it didn't bring app to show on Main content but I typed URL /dashboard/home. it did show the work on Main content. So I updated the post.  In the dashboard.component.ts , I create function for click. I don't know it was good or not.  *Thanks for the idea.

Comment: * I solve it. In the dashboard.component.ts. I route to these url. 
home() {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home']);
  }
  employee(){
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/employee']);
  }
}

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You probably also want to use `routerLink` on your buttons so you don‘t have to do it in typescript. Just also don‘t have to specify an absolute path (starting with a `/`) to this array, but this is explained in detail here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: If this did solve your problem, please remember to accept my answer and close your question.

Comment: I accepted your answer but Stack overflow doesn't allow me to close my question.